# Can't access EC2 instance via public IP address from browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I deployed an angular app on ec2 machine on nginx server but when I try to access the ec2 machine via public ip address using browser it gives below error :

This site can’t be reached.  refused to connect.

I checked all the settings and followed all the solutions but still getting same error. Please refer the screenshots for the settings done so far to resolve this issue.

Please advise. Thanks in advance.

Security group settings :

[image]

Subnet is attached

[image]

Internet gateway is attached to the subnet

[image]

Windows Firewall settings

[image]

Comment: If you `ssh` into the Amazon EC2 instance and run `curl localhost`, does it return anything?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein

I get the following response after following your instructions.

       __|  __|_  )
       _|  (     /   Amazon Linux 2 AMI
      ___|\___|___|

https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-2/

       __|  __|_  )
       _|  (     /   Amazon Linux 2 AMI
      ___|\___|___|

https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-2/
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-33-115 ~]$ localhost
-bash: localhost: command not found
*[ec2-user@ip-172-31-33-115 ~]$ curl localhost
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80 after 0 ms: Connection refused*
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-33-115 ~]$

Comment: The fact that `curl localhost` fails says that no software is listening on port 80 of the computer. You say that you "deployed an angular app on ec2 machine on nginx server", so what port is it running on? If it is port 443, then try `curl localhost:443`

Comment: @JohnRotenstein
You are absolutely right. For now, I just changed the port to 80 and it is working fine. I faced same problem previously and the reason was same, nothing installed to listen on that port so even if the port was open, the connection got refused. Thanks a lot John